# Facebook real time updates don't work on posts with location?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I made a `Facebook` application asking for `user_status`, `user_checkins` and `user_likes`.
I also subscribed to the real time updates of my users for the `"checkins,feed,likes"` fields.

When my users like pages I receive an updates so everything is working fine on this part.

I have weird issue on checkins though, when I try with my `iPad` I receive the checkin update. But when I do the same thing on my `Android` I don't receive anything.

The difference is that I see my `iPad` checkins on :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?access_token=AAA[...]
```

But I find my `Android` "checkins" on :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?with=location&access_token=AAA[...]
```

I thought I should receive them as a "feed" update but I don't receive them either.

Am I missing something?

---

### UPDATE

OK I was clearly missing something.

In order to have those "feed" updates you must ask for the permission `read_stream`.